# Starter motor 'stutters' (Mk1 Golf)

Tags: vw, starter, golf

Recently the starter motor on my VW Mk1 Golf seems to be stuttering when starting. The car starts fine and in the same amount of revolutions as always, but the starter motor sounds like it is coughing.

Time for a replacement starter motor? Or a battery issue?

Comment: A battery issue can easily be ruled out by temporarily using another battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mk1 Golf there is a bush at the ring gear end of the starter motor which could be causing the problem.  It could be caused by failing ring gear on the flywheel, a bad earth strap or simply an aging starter motor.

The good news is that the starter is easily removed and nothing is particularly expensive.